# IIS NON-WWW to WWW Rewrite Issue with SSL certificate

Tags: https, url-rewriting, security-certificate, iis, no-www

*I have a SSL related redirection problem with ISS as follows:*

- `http://example.com` redirects to `https://example.com`

  - This works perfectly.
- `http://www.example.com` redirects to `https://www.example.com`

  - Does not work perfectly, browsers report an issue with the SSL certification.

*Question(s):*

How can I resolve the issue with either the redirect or SSL certification?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check the common name on the certificate you purchased from your CA. While some CA's will give you a bonus subject alternate name of `www.example.com` if you buy a certificate using common name of `example.com` (and vice versa), others do not and your cert could just be bound to the common name of `example.com`.

Your certificate error doesn't look to be related to your redirect but to the common name bound to the certificate. Any web browser should give you the ability to view additional details on that certificate warning in order to determine why the warning is getting thrown.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I just checked and the common name is `example.com`. I did notice that I have two certificates, one for `example.com` and one for `www.example.com`. This all started when one expired and I had to renew it. I am sure I am the cause of my own problems here!

Comment: Okay, I think I found the problem. It looks like `www.example.com` is using the `example.com` certificate, which I believe is throwing the certificate error when going to `www.example.com`. I realize this is all probably "first-grade" stuff to you guys, so I just want to say thank you for your help, comments and patients.

Answer (score 0):

*You can strip the `www` from the URL using this method:*

> [SOURCE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21823480/1892635):
>
> ```
> <rule name="Remove www" stopProcessing="true">
>   <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
>   <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
>     <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.(.+)$" />
>   </conditions>
>   <action type="Redirect" url="http://{C:1}/{R:0}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
> </rule>
> ```

Comment: That doesn't resolve the certificate issue.